# Fragmentation processes function in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function that has two variables `x` and `D` where each variable is a function. (I put them in the code below as an array as a test).

What I want is to run the function many times, where each time I use one set of values for `x` and `D` to get the `Sec_nucli`, then use the result `Sec_nucli` as a new input, again and again.

I have tried this:

```
x   = np.array([16.7, 16.5, 16.1, 15, 13.5,14.2, 14.9, 13.7])  # an example
D   = np.array([0, 1, 4, 7, 16, 31, 64, 127])  # example
n_H = 0.9

Sec_nucli = []
x         = []
D         = []

for i in range(1, n): 
    Sec_nucli[i] =  n_H * D * xsec[i]
    sec_nucli += sec_nucli[i]
    return sec_nucli

## I defined the function like this:
def Fragmentation():
    n_H = 0.9
    Sec_nucli[i]=  n_H *D* x[i]
    return Sec_nucli
```

Comment: And the problem is ____?

Comment: I don't now if this is correct?!

Comment: Correct is relative. A program that throws an error could be considered correct, if that was its intention. Is your code not working as expected? Then what is expected and what is actual result?

Comment: Please indent your code better.

Answer (score -1):

```html
Sec_nucli = 0

def Fragmentation(D,x):
    s_nucli = n_H * D * x
    return s_nucli
for xi in x: 
    for Dj in D:
      print(xi, Dj)
      Sec_nucli += Fragmentation(xi,Dj)
      print(Sec_nucli)
```